# Recovering partly overwritten LVM

Tags: lvm, storage-area-network

We had multiple servers connected to a SAN (via Fiber Channel) to run Proxmox (a KVM solution).

One of the servers needed to be reinstalled so we let it perform an automated install (via kickstart). What we didn't know was that the server's hard drive had failed, which caused it to select the first available hard drive (the SAN disk) and install linux on that. This meant it overwrote the LVM on the SAN disk and the first x Gbytes.

We're certain we'll lose some data, but we were trying to recover the LVM by using the files in /etc/lvm/backup or /etc/lvm/archive. We followed a lot of advise only, used *pvcreate* with the *--uuid* and *--restorefile* and then used *vgcfgrestore* to restore.

The result is we see the logical volumes again, with their original name and size. We expect the first one to not work anymore, but were expecting to recover the others.
When we start the KVM virtual machines, they refuse to find the drives.

My suspicion is that there's a mismatch with the exact starting sector on disk, but I have no clue how to find and correct this.

Does anyone have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to recover the data by using testdisk to scan the entire drive for partitions, then mount the first linux partitions after every swap partition using a loop device (using the --offset parameter being the first sector * 512 bytes).